# Resources release while coding on Haxe (mainly for XML parser disposal)?

Tags: haxe

I'm new to Haxe coming from Actionscript. I was looking for ways to dispose resources when I can't reuse them. In particular, is there something like the Actionscript's "System.disposeXML" for Haxe's Fast XML?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the targets you're referring to? A lot of what happens will depend on the language target you're compiling to :)

Comment: Mainly HTML5 and Flash itself.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the target platform, but in Javascript/AS3, to have an object or graph of objects be disposed of, simply make sure there are no references to it anywhere in your program. The garbage collector will take care of it.

What `disposeXML` does seems to be overkill. For modern garbage collectors, you don't need to break all references within the group, just those referring to any member of it.